# mysql service status doesn't show started when it is started by monit

Tags: mysql, monit

I installed monit on my Ubuntu 14.04 server and configured it to monitor mysql with the below config in monitrc.

```
 check process mysqld with pidfile /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
 start program = "/etc/init.d/mysql start"
 stop program = "/etc/init.d/mysql stop"
```

Now to test I shutdown mysql user

```
 service mysql stop
```

Monit does restart the server but the issue is that when I service status on mysql like below

```
 service mysql status
```

It shows

```
 mysql stop/waiting
```

But when I do

```
 ps -e | grep "mysql"
```

I see the mysqld service running.

Any ideas why service mysql status wont show me running?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the mysql process you see in ps have the same pidfile as listed in /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid? Also should replace /etc/init.d/mysql start|stop in monit config with adequate service command.

Comment: Yes it has the same id

Comment: Ok, thats a good starting point :) Replace the start|stop commands as suggested, restart mysql service manually and see if monit recognizes it. Then start/stop service via monit ans see if that works. From my experience monit struggles sometimes during initial setup but works fine afterwards (I cant tell a reason for this). Also check the monit template for mysql in /etc/monit/monitrc.d/ - it covers much more than yours.

Comment: Tried to put service command instead /etc/init.d/mysql but monit doesn't know what is service.

Comment: replace service with /usr/bin/service (or whatever 'whereis service' hands you out)